# Drupal 6: Make a menu_hook() return a specific view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I created a hook in order to add an item to the administrator's menu. When the user clicks on the item, I want to return the content of a specific view I created. How should I return the view?

My current code looks like:

```
function my_view_menu(){
   $items['view'] = array(
    'title' => 'Report', 
    'page callback' => 'return_my_view', 
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );    
   return $items;
}

function return_my_view(){
  return t("Hello!");
}
```

**EDIT:**

As suggested by Berdir, this the correct way to call a view:

```
function return_my_view(){
  $viewName = 'my_report'; // use the machine readable name of the view
  return views_embed_view($viewName);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want views_embed_view(), see http://web.archive.org/web/20110213234806/http://thedrupalblog.com/embedding-view-drupal-6-using-views-embed-view

Comment: Hi Bedir, I updated my question using the code you provided, however now a blank page is returned (instead of the "Hello!" message).

Comment: If there is a so called WSOD, you need to find out why: http://drupal.org/node/158043.

Comment: Thanks! As pointed out by Nelson, the problem was that my view's name was not correct :) I will accept your answer since you led me in the right direction and upvote Nelson's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You could just add a menu item in the view itself...and restrict access (to the view) to the admin role of choice :)

1. In your view choose "page" and click
   on the "Add Display" button (if there isn't already a page display).
2. Under
   "Page Settings" add a Path and a
   Normal Menu-Entry in the Navigation
   Menu
3. Next Under Basic Settings
   change the access to Role based and
   choose the role(s) that should have
   access
4. Finally go to the
   navigation menu settings and drag
   the new menu item to the desired
   place in the Administer menu

Comment: Could explain a bit how you would add a menu item to the view itself? I'm new to Drupal and would prefer not to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: +1 Wow, that is a lot more elegant than my solution :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

views_embed_view() is the correct call. If you are getting a blank page, try checking your apache error log to see if there are any php errors. I also notice that in your revised example you used $viewName = "my-report", but views_embed_view() expects the machine readable name of the view, which only allows for alphanumeric and underscore characters. Perhaps you are using the incorrect name?

Comment: Oh, of course, when the view doesn't exist, that function call returns NULL, and if you return NULL from a page_callback, then Drupal doesn't render the site at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick. However no php errors got logged until I called the execute() method on my view object. This way I could see that the object was pointing to null.

Answer (score 2):

Third technique: Once you have created a Page Display for a View, Views will provision that page with a menu entry. Once that exists, it is possible to duplicate that menu entry for your own purposes.

1. Create a module with a weight of at least 11 (higher weight than Views)
2. Implement `hook_menu_alter()` and duplicate the View entry.

   ```
   function example_menu_alter(&$items) {
     $items['admin/new/path'] = $items['original/view/path'];
   }
   ```

This approach is somewhat convoluted, but is sometimes a useful alternative for Views or other "page" content you want to clone.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to berdir's comment, you can also skip the intermediate callback function and just call views_embed_view directly from your menu router:

```
function hook_menu(){
   $items['path/to/my/view'] = array(
    'title' => 'Report', 
    'page callback' => 'views_embed_view',
    'page arguments' => array('my-view-name'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );    
  return $items;
}
```